# Angular 7 rxjs/operator/debounceTime on Subject duplicate action

Tags: angular, rxjs6

In an Angular7 application, I captured the KeyUp event of a numeric input with this html code:

```
<input fxFlex
     type="number" 
     formControlName="DM"
     (keyup)="changeDM()">
</div>
```

I use debounceTime(500) to delay call to a service that processes the form. I write a 1, 2, 3, 4 ... digit number and I see that the debounceTime(500) works correctly, but it makes a duplicate call to the service. Look the code:

```
subject: Subject<any> = new Subject();

.....

this.subj.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(() => {
    console.log('==CALL TO SERVICE==');
    this.service.setForm( this.form.valid, this.form.value );
});

changeDM(): void { 
    console.log('changeDM==============');
    this.subject.next();
}
```

And the image of the browser console with four keyup:

[image]

Why is the service called two times?
Thank you.

image in which I show the input content after each press. Pulse 8 and wait more than 500 ms., Pulse 4567 ... You can see the result.

[image]

Comment: Do you also have this behavior when you type only one character?   most probably you didnt type all your characters within 500ms... debouncetime just keeps the last emitted value within the time interval.  please check the marble diagram here. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime

Comment: I am guessing the error is somewhere else than in the code you have posted here as this should be working. Also I see that this is not the actual code as you are declaring the variable "subject" and then you call "this.subj". Could you copy / paste us more of your code?

Comment: jcuypers: Effectively, I get the same result when I press a single key. In the original post I have put an image in which I show the content after each press. Pulse 8 and wait more than 500 ms., Pulse 4567 ... You can see the result.

Comment: snorredan: It is not the original code but there is no more code related to this event. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Debouncetime just keeps the last emitted value within the time interval.  please check the marble diagram here. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime

Answer (score 0):

I also had some trouble with this same scenario, hope it helps you/someone. [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fi8blx)

I had a bit of a difficult time wrapping my head around observable and observer. He's a bit about how it happens and linked is the article for more in-depth takeaways.

> We make use of an RxJS Subject, which acts as both an Observable and an Observer. Our subject has a next() method that we’ll use in the template to pass our search term to the subject as we type. 
>   [real-time-search-angular-rxjs](https://alligator.io/angular/real-time-search-angular-rxjs/)

```js
export class Example {
  response: any;
  term$: Subject < string > = new Subject < string > ();

  constructor(private exampleSerivce: ExampleService) {
    this.exampleSerivce.search(this.term$).subscribe(res => this.response = res);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  search(term: Observable < string > ) {
    return term.pipe(
      filter(val => !!val),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(500),
      switchMap(term => this.searchTodo(term)),
      catchError(() => {
        return of({
          error: 'no todo found'
        });
      })
    );
  }

  searchTodo(term: string) {
    return this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${term}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Input - Numbers only please" (keyup)="term$.next($event.target.value)">
  </mat-form-field>

  <div class="todo">
    {{response | json}}
  </div>
</div>
```